# Attempt to read property "email_from" on string

Tags: php, laravel, string

Having error from this

```
           $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;        
        }        
        $mail->Port       = $config->port;        
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';        
        //Recipients        
        $mail->setFrom($gnl->email_from, $gnl->sitetitle);        
        $mail->addAddress($receiver_email, $receiver_name);        
        $mail->addReplyTo($gnl->email_from, $gnl->sitename);        
        // Content        
        $mail->isHTML(true);        
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
```

This is were my error is from

```
$mail->setFrom($gnl->email_from, $gnl->sitetitle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that the property name 'email_from' exists in the `$gnl` object and that it's spelled correctly.

```
if (is_object($gnl)) {
    if (property_exists($gnl, 'email_from')) {
        $mail->setFrom($gnl->email_from, $gnl->sitetitle);
    } else {
        echo "Property 'email_from' does not exist in the \$gnl object.";
    }
} else {
    echo "\$gnl is not an object.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the $gnl variable is actually a string rather than an object which you assume it is.

Do a bit of ddd() debugging earlier on to see where the $gnl variable comes from.